# Powershell Parameter Set and

Tags: powershell

I have a function that I want to have require a filename, and Output string and an optional array of values (basically everything else passed to the function)

The initial starting point of the declaration is as follows:

```
func {
    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Default", Position=1)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Variable", Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
    [String]$FileName, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Default", Position=2)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Variable", Position=2)]
    [String]$Output, 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="Default", Position=3)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Variable", ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true )]
    [string[]]$Variables 

    )
}
```

However, I am unable to get the function to behave as I intend.  I get the following error when I call the function:

```
func: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At S:\PS\Home\Library\PSStdLib\PSStdLib.psm1:595 char:9
+         func"$psExecutionLog" "{0,-19} {1,-35} {2,-25} {3,-25} { ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [func], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,func
```

I have been staring at this for hours.  I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong.  I just cannot see it.

Comment: how do you invoke the method? Why are you define the parameter properties twice?

Comment: Did the answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell is getting confused by which ParameterSet to use.

- You function is invalid. Missing `function` keyword
- There's no need for ParameterSets to have one optional parameter.
- You don't have to tell `ValueFromRemainingArguments` to be mandatory (and the parameter itself to be optional). Either there are arguments, the parameter is explictly called or there is not value.

I would ignore parameterssets and just do this.

```
function func {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [String]$FileName, 

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
        [String]$Output, 

        [Parameter(Position=3, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [string[]]$Variables 

    )
}
```

Be aware that `ValueFromRemainingArguments` can make usage a bit confusing. If `-Variables` is used a parameter, array-elements are separated by comma `,`. If you use it to catch arguments, the elements are separated with whitespace. You can't use both at the same time (explictly using parameter and catching arguments).

```
#No parameter or arguments
func -FileName "file" -Output "out"

#Parameter
func -FileName "file" -Output "out" -Variables "hello","world"

#ValueFromRemainingArguments
func -FileName "file" -Output "out" "hello" "world"

#ERROR: Can't use both parameter and ValueFromRemainingArguments at the same time
func -FileName "file" -Output "out" -Variables "hello","world" "foo"
```